# Postgres auto tuning

Tags: postgresql

As we all know postgres performance highly depends on config params. Eg if I have ssd drive or more RAM I need to tell that postgres by changing relevant cfg param

I wonder if there is any tool (for Linux) which can suggest best postgres configuration for current hardware?

Im aware Websites (eg pgtune) where I can enter server spec and those can suggest best config

However each hardware is different (eg I might have better raid / controller or some processes what might consume more ram etc). My wish would be postgres doing  self tuning, analysing query execution time available resources etc

Understand there is no such mechanism, so maybe there is some tool / script I can run which can do this job for me (checking eg disk seq. / random disk read, memory available  etc) and telling me what to change in config

Comment: Must be a conspiracy of the PostgreSQL support providers, but I never heard of such a tool.

Answer (score 1):

There are parameters that you can tweak to get better performance from postgresql.

This [article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/08/31/tuning-postgresql-database-parameters-to-optimize-performance/) gives good read about that.
There are few scripts that can do that. One that is mentioned in postgres wiki is [this one](https://github.com/jfcoz/postgresqltuner).

To get more idea about what more tuning your database needs, you need to log its request and performance, after analysing those logs you can tune more params. For this there is [pgbadger](https://github.com/darold/pgbadger) log analyzer.

After using database in production, you get more idea regarding what requirements you have and how to approach them rather than making changes just based on `os or hardware configuration`.

Comment: Thanks - will check this later today and see what those tools say :)